# JavaScript buttons not working; code is identical to other working buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm programming a website using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I have two buttons on a page that use JavaScript to display information when clicked (each button fades out the others information when clicked to save space). But the same code isn't working for my other buttons?

**JavaScript**:

```
<script type = text/javascript>
$('#scoreButton20102011').click(function() {
    $("#maleRec20102011").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#femaleRec20102011").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#maleRec20112012").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#femaleRec20112012").fadeOut(1000);
});
$('#scoreButton20112012').click(function() {
    $("#maleRec20112012").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#femaleRec20112012").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#maleRec20102011").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#femaleRec20102011").fadeOut(1000);
});​
</script>
```

The button for 2010/11 shows up both buttons text, and the button for 2011/12 makes everything fade out? I cannot see why.

**CSS**:

```
#maleRec20112012 {
    border-top: 3px solid #000;
    border-left: 3px solid #000;
    border-right: 3px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    right: 0;
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
}

#femaleRec20112012 {
    border-top: 3px solid #E6E6DC;
    border-left: 3px solid #E6E6DC;
    border-right: 3px solid #E6E6DC;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
}

#maleRec20102011 {
    border-top: 3px solid #E6E6DC;
    border-left: 3px solid #E6E6DC;
    border-right: 3px solid #E6E6DC;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
}

#femaleRec20102011 {
    border-top: 3px solid #E6E6DC;
    border-left: 3px solid #E6E6DC;
    border-right: 3px solid #E6E6DC;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Is your jQuery at the end of your page or in a document.ready call? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ to show the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
   <script type = text/javascript>
            $('#scoreButton20102011').live('click',function()
            {
                $("#maleRec20102011").fadeIn(1000);
                $("#femaleRec20102011").fadeIn(1000);
                $("#maleRec20112012").fadeOut(1000);
                $("#femaleRec20112012").fadeOut(1000);                  
            });
            $('#scoreButton20112012').live('click',function()
            {
                $("#maleRec20112012").fadeIn(1000);
                $("#femaleRec20112012").fadeIn(1000);
                $("#maleRec20102011").fadeOut(1000);
                $("#femaleRec20102011").fadeOut(1000);
            });

        </script>
```

or try to put the code in onready function

Comment: same problem with this im afraid! will try just one function

Comment: load the page and press ctrl+shift+j and see there is an error or not ??

Answer (score 0):

Does this simplified  JSFiddle work as you intended? http://jsfiddle.net/9JAGK/ If so, I'd guess your problem is actually elsewhere in your code. Maybe check for any other events that might be assigned to your buttons or styles that might be conflicting with the fadeIn/fadeOut?